# Are there references to Jesus in the Jerusalem Talmud?

Tags: christianity, talmud-yerushalmi, censorship

In my online search I have not come across any references to Jesus in the Talmud Yerushalmi. I realize in the Bavli sometimes he is not identified by name or passages are censored/removed. I would like to know if there are any references to Jesus (or a person of another name who shares some characteristics of the 'historical' Jesus) that can be found in the Talmud Yerushalmi

Comment: The Yerushalmi usually does not concern itself with stories ,so makes sense ישו does not make it in

Comment: There's very little Aggada in the Yerushalmi. It's not like the Bavli. I don't know if Jesus is mentioned or not, but it wouldn't surprise me if he isn't.

Comment: @sam and DoubleAA that sounds like a worthwhile answer.

Comment: plenty of agadah in chagigah; if you call it that @DoubleAA

Comment: 2 down votes? really?

Comment: See "[Jesus in the Talmud](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=IxIv_zqQx9kC)" by Peter Schäfer for a comprehensive discussion.

Comment: No, there are no references to Jesus at all, whatsoever, in the Talmud.

Comment: @TurkHill, there are many references, not none "at all, whatsoever".  E.g. see Argon's suggested reference, or look at Sanhedrin 43a: "*On Passover Eve they hung the corpse of Jesus the Nazarene after they killed him by way of stoning. And a crier went out before him for forty days, publicly proclaiming: Jesus the Nazarene is going out to be stoned because he practiced sorcery, incited people to idol worship, and led the Jewish people astray.*".  Or search for [Jesus the Nazarene](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=Jesus%20the%20Nazarene) in The Sefaria Library.

Comment: @RayButterworth In his book "Kosher Jesus" Rabbi Shmuley Boteach explains that these references are not referring to the Christian Jesus but another Jesus. If you go back 2000yrs you will notice that when you shout the name "Jesus" at least 20 heads would turn. "Jesus," Yeshu, was a popular name in ancient Israel. Just because the Talmud "mentions" a "Jesus" does not mean it's talking about Christianity's Jesus at all.

Comment: @TurkHill, so it was a common tradition to execute Jesuses from Nazareth on Passover eve.

Comment: @RayButterworth I can only say that I suggest that you at least read Rabbi Shmuley Boteach before making a decision.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, Mr. J. wasn't only referred to by his name, he had other names that referenced him ([see Jastrow](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%A1%D6%B7%D7%98%D6%B0%D7%93%D6%B8%D6%BC%D7%90?lang=bi), [Wiki,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_in_the_Talmud) [Jewish Wiki](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95)). Thus, only searching his name will not always yield results. Secondly, the Talmud Yerushalmi was censored just like the Bavli - something to keep in mind. In general, many 'famous' passages found in the Bavli were earlier teachings that were compiled into the Yerushalmi long before the Bavli was completed, so there is often overlap.

Shabbat 14:4 presents a story which also appears in Bavli [Avodah Zarah 27b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.27b.6?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) (and Tosefta, Chulin 2; see Tosafot, Sanhedrin 27b, Ed. Oz Vehahdar, note #20). [This](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24412&st=&pgnum=149&hilite=) discuses the censorship in Yerushalmi and [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22221&st=&pgnum=73) the Bavli.

[Yerushalmi [standard] censored:](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r2114.htm)

> מעשה בר' אלעזר בן דמה שנשכו נחש ובא יעקב איש כפר סמא לרפותו ולא הני לו ר' ישמעאל.  אמר לו אני מביא ראייה שירפאנו לא הספיק להביא ראייה עד שמת בן דמה.

Uncensored, according to [here](https://shiurcentral.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/d799d7a9d795-d794d7a0d7a6d7a8d799.pdf) (See Plates 1, 2):

> מעשה בר' אלעזר בן דמה שנשכו נחש ובא יעקב איש כפר סמא **משם של ישו פנדירא** לרפותו
> ולא הניח לו רבי ישמעאל אמר לו אני מביא ראייה שירפאני לא הספיק להביא ראייה עד שמת
> בן דמה

The consensus is that *איש כפר סמא* was in relation with Mr. J. himself one way or another, if not said directly in his name.

Yevamot 16:6 ([from here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95)) mentions the equivalent (additions in) [Bavli 67a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.67a.15?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) (more discussion [here](http://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=5760)). [Munich Manuscript does not have yeshu either; see Plate 6]

> ישו בן פנדירא נתלה בערב פסח בלוד משום שהסית, ואף הכמינו עדים בשביל להרוג אותו על כה

However, all [Yerushalmi](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r3116.htm) versions of the incident only mention ben stada; see Plates, 3, 4. The Leiden Manuscript (Plate 5) seems to have a corrupted version, with lines drawn on top, perhaps indicating the corrupted text.

> שכן עשו **לבן סטדא** בלוד שהכמינו לו שני תלמידי חכמים והביאוהו לבית דין וסקלוהו

[Plate 1: Shabbat, Venice 1523 - The Chaim Elozor Reich z"l / Renaissance Hebraica Collection][12]
[![Shabat][13]][13]

[Plate 2: Shabbat, Kraków 1609 -
The Chaim Elozor Reich z"l / Renaissance Hebraica Collection](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46006&st=&pgnum=27)
[image: shabbat]

[Plate 3: Yevamot, Kraków 1609 -
The Chaim Elozor Reich z"l / Renaissance Hebraica Collection](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46008&st=&pgnum=29)
[image: Yebamot]

[Plate 4: Yevamot, Venice 1523 - The Chaim Elozor Reich z"l / Renaissance Hebraica Collection](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45298&st=&pgnum=325)
[image: Yebamot]

[Plate 5: Yevamot, Leiden Manuscript 1289](http://www.yerushalmionline.org/manuscripts/)
[image: yebamot]

[Plate 6: Sanhedrin, Munich Manuscript 1342](https://www.wdl.org/en/item/8910/)
[image: Sanhedrin]

Comment: It also appears in AZ perek 2

Comment: There is an old manuscript ,will check it to see if that Yerushalmi has it

Comment: I couldn't manage to download the one on yerushalmi online's website; thanks @sam

Comment: Consider editing para. “The consensus”; is second “was” supposed to say “with? (The consensus is that this ‘Jacob’ was saying/healing in the name of Jesus.)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It doesn't appear that there are any references other than those which can also be found in the Bavli

Comment: @rikitikitembo [This](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36791&st=&pgnum=729) essay, by Dr. [Solomon Zeitlin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Zeitlin), should be of interest to you.

Comment: @rikitikitembo [Here’s](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36791&st=&pgnum=716) a more direct link to the afore cited essay.

Comment: And another thorough [essay](https://books.google.com/books?id=RxEHAQAAIAAJ&lpg=PA480&ots=HiBUKRhzKg&dq=jacob%20lauterbach%20jesus%20in%20talmud&pg=PA473#v=onepage&q&f=false) on the topic (dispelling common theories) by [Jacob Lauterbach](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Zallel_Lauterbach).